# JQuery each loop looping through one line of code x amount of times before even looking at the rest

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a loop in Jquery:

```
var fadeTime=500;
css_id=0;
$.each(my_array, function (i, d_U) {
css_id++;
an_v=d_U[1];
an_d=d_U[4];

do_c_function("id_344",true,true);

$("#box_"+css_id).fadeIn(fadeTime,function(){

   //this stuff will happen once the fadein is complete

   $("#box_"+css_id).animate({top: '-50px'},fadeTime,function(){

       //this stuff will happen once the animate is complete

       alert("#box_"+css_id);//for debugging

    });//end of animation

  });//end of fadein

});//end of each loop
```

Now as you've probably noticed, I'm trying to make the loop animate different divs each time using the `css_id` variable and `++;` (add 1) to it each time the loop runs.

Thing is, `css_id` reaches a high value before any of the code below has even been executed once. So when its time to animate, Jquery will try to animate `#box_210` when its supposed to animate `#box_1`.

Is there any way to make it only execute the `css_id++;` line once, then the animate lines get executed, and only then again with the `css_id++;` line...and so on.

I've tried to put the `css_id++;` line in a call back with both the animations but that seems to not work as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your animate callback function is forming a closure over `css_id` and therefore storing a live reference to `css_id`, not merely the value this variable holds at the moment the animation loop is created.

Since all parameters are passed by value in JavaScript, you can use jQuery's data function to break the closure, and take a snapshot of the css_id value at that time.

```
    $("#box_"+css_id).data("css_id", css_id).fadeIn(fadeTime,function(){
       var local_css_id = $(this).data("css_id");
       $("#box_"+ local_css_id).animate({top: '-50px'},fadeTime,function(){

           //this stuff will happen once the animate is complete

           alert("#box_" + local_css_id);//for debugging
        });//end of animation
      });//end of fadein    
    });//end of each loop
```

Comment: hey, just tried the code and its doing the exact same thing. thanks

Comment: I don't see the use for `setTimeout`.

Comment: @JamesMontagne - as I understand the question, the loop is burning through 90% of its iterations before the first fadeOut starts.  I think OP wants these animations spread out more evenly.

Comment: The issue still hasn't gone away mate. Seems to do the fadein perfectly fine but the animate only does the last div (because css_id has reached the last number).

Comment: @Nav - I think the problem is what I said it was from the beginning, but didn't adequately diagnose: callbacks are forming closures over css_id.  See my updated answer

Comment: @Nav - thanks for your patience...glad I was finally able to help :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the scope of `css_id`.  The easiest way to fix it would be to call a function within your loop.  Each call to the function will get its own parameter in the scope of the function which will not change as the variable is incremented.

Something like this:

```
function doTheAnimation(css_id) {
    $("#box_" + css_id).fadeIn(fadeTime, function() {

        //this stuff will happen once the fadein is complete
        $("#box_" + css_id).animate({
            top: '-50px'
        }, fadeTime, function() {

            //this stuff will happen once the animate is complete
            alert("#box_" + css_id); //for debugging
        }); //end of animation
    }); //end of fadein   
}

var fadeTime = 500;
css_id = 0;
$.each(my_array, function(i, d_U) {
    css_id++;
    an_v = d_U[1];
    an_d = d_U[4];

    do_c_function("id_344", true, true);

    doTheAnimation(css_id);

}); //end of each loop
```

Here is a fiddle to illustrate the difference.

http://jsfiddle.net/kmGWa/

Answer (score 0):

If you want each animation to go in sequence (the next one starting after the previous one is done), you can code it like this where each one is done in a local function and the final completion function invokes the local function again to do the next one:

```
function doFades() {
    var fadeTime=500;
    css_id=0;
    var i = 0;
    function doOneFade() {
        if (i < my_array.length) {
            var d_U = my_array[i++];
            css_id++;
            an_v=d_U[1];
            an_d=d_U[4];

            do_c_function("id_344",true,true);

            $("#box_"+css_id).fadeIn(fadeTime,function(){

               //this stuff will happen once the fadein is complete

               $("#box_"+css_id).animate({top: '-50px'},fadeTime,function(){

                   //this stuff will happen once the animate is complete

                   alert("#box_"+css_id);//for debugging
                   doOneFade();

               });//end of animation

           });//end of fadein
       }
   }
   doOneFade();
}
```